Different patterns with "neither nor"


Since early childhood, I have spoken with a stutter. Neither of my parents does, nor had either of them known stutterers before I was born. (Newyorker)


I find although the sentence above has "neither" and "nor", but they work separately.  I'm trying to express roughly the same idea with different patterns, where "neither" and "nor" work together.

My parents neither speak with a stutter, nor had they known stutterers before I was born.

Neither do my parents speak with a stutter,nor had they known stutterers before I was born.

My parents don't speak with a stutter, nor had they known   stutterers before I was born.

My parents neither speak with a stutter, nor had known stutterers before I was born.


I think they all work except (3),  Am I right?

I think they all work, but (3) sounds rather pompous and over-formal.

2 sounds a bit formal to me; inversion usually sound formal. It's a bit of an awkward sentence because of the two different tenses and because "neither" could mean "neither of your parents" or could contrast with "nor" so it's ambiguous or confusing. ("Neither do either of my parents speak with a stutter, nor had they known stutterers" is technically OK but would be odd.) I might avoid "neither nor" entirely in this case (shrug emoji).

The original is fine. "Neither of my parents stutter" does not need to be followed by a "nor" because the word 'neither' functions as a pronoun to indicate "not either" of the parents.
Your other examples use "neither...nor" as a correlative conjunction pair connecting the two list items. They may be grammatically okay, but logically they are a bit off. They all group your "parents" together when in fact you are speaking about their individual experiences and speaking ability. Stick to the original.
